# public_activity gem decorated with Draper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, draper

I'm trying to decorate a collection of activities created by the public_activity gem using Draper.

However, it appears that PublicActivity::Activity doesn't inherit from ActiveRecord (am I right in assuming that?) so I need to add `include Draper::Decoratable` to the model, but where is that PublicActivity model exactly?

Btw, this is the error I'm getting:

`Could not infer a decorator for PublicActivity::Activity.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it turns out that this won't work:

```
class StudentActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").decorate
  end
end
```

I'm guessing this is because the namespaced query `PublicActivity::Activty` doesn't inherit from ActiveRecord and therefore doesn't include `Draper::Decoratable`, but I'm not sure. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

However, with Draper you can decorate objects as well as queries, so this **does work**...

```
class StudentActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
    @activities = StudentActivitiesDecorator.decorate_collection(@activities)
  end
end
```

The decorator must also include `decorates PublicActivity::Activity`

Answer (score 3):

Just put `activity_decorator.rb` in `decorators/public_activity`:

```
# app/decorators/public_activity/activity_decorator.rb

class PublicActivity::ActivityDecorator < Draper::Decorator
end
```